# Validation with override setter find_or_initialize_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a form, I have a multiselect dropdown that I can manually sort. I override the setter method to achieve this. However, when I add validation, I get the presence error saying that `"Tags cannot be blank"` even when there are tags selected in the dropdown.

```
params: {tag_ids: ['', '1', '3']}
```

I think it has something to do with validating before saving which happens in the override function. Any suggestions in how I can make it to run the validations after running the setter method or vice-versa? Thanks.

Controller:

```
def update
 if @article.update(article_params)
  redirect_to articles_path
 end
end

def article_params
 params.require(:article).permit(:title, tag_ids: [])
end
```

Models:

```
class Article
 has_many: :article_tags
 has_many: :tags, through: :article_tags

 validates: :tag_ids, presence: true
 
 def tag_ids=(ids)
  ids = ids.reject(&:blank?)
  self.article_tags.where.not(article_tag_id: ids).destroy_all
  ids.each_with_index do |id, idx|
   article_tag= self.article_tags.find_or_initialize_by(article_tag_id: id)
   if self.new_record?
    article_tag.ordinal = idx + 1
   else
    article_tag.update(ordinal: idx + 1)
   end
  end
 end

 def tags
  super.joins(:article_tags).order("article_tags.ordinal").distinct
 end
end

class ArticleTag
 belongs_to: :article
 belongs_to: :tag
end
```

Comment: You have somewhat complex logic inside this `tag_ids` method. Either step through it with manual debugging i.e. `binding.pr` or better to use TDD to make sure your method is behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: @lacostenycoder the logic works just fine, but the moment I add `validates: :tag_ids, presence: true` it throws an error saying "Cannot be blank" even when it is not.

Comment: Clearly there's something you're missing.  But it's not clear what that is. Do you have the full backtrace errors? If so maybe post them in your question.  Do you have a unit test for this method?

Comment: first, try to do without any validation and later implement custom validation

Comment: @lacostenycoder I do not have a full trace of errors since there is no errors at this point. find_or_initilize_by creates a new item if the record cannot be found. However, when validation is running it will never initialize it since the validation runs before the setter method. But if I add a custom validation after checking for it, it will throw an error saying that the foreign key is missing since the article has not been created yet.

Comment: @IgorKasyanchuk without validation will work since it creates the records after creating the article. But adding validation runs it before anything is done so it will always be empty..